# How to get sql data bases instances in azure using java api

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, java

I'm working with Azure Java API in Eclipse.
In my program, I get the Azure credentials from the user. In this way I can use for example the Blob storage service using the Java API for Azure.
But my problem is when I want to manage the data bases deployed in Azure SQL service. My question is if I can list the data bases that the user have created in his Azure account using the Java API and the Azure credentials.

Comment: You should explain your problem more clearly, this is a bit too broad and might not attract a good answer.

Comment: To clarify, when you say Azure credentials, do you mean the azure subscription (i.e., cert-based authentication)?